# Ajax method call in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Getting some issue in calling ajax method in codeigniter.I am trying to 
    call controller method using AJAX function call on dropdown change event.
    Dropdown change event is being use for ajax call. Ajax call is working 
    perfectly for initial 2 or 3 change event but after that ajax call is 
    not working
    My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on('change', '#assettype_id', function(e) {
   var categoryval = $('#assettype_id :selected').val();
  // assettype_id is dropdown id. On change event of 
   // dropdown, controller method will be called

myurl = 'http://mylocalsite/index.php/controllername/controllermethod/' + $.now();

alert("category id = " + categoryval); // for testing
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    id: categoryval
  },
  url: myurl,
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data1) {
    alert("inside ajax call"); // for testing
    $('#result').html("");
    // result is a div tag used to display result//
    $("#result").html(data1);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('error');
  },
  complete: function(xhr, status) {
    alert("The request is complete!");
  }
   });
 });
});
```

Sharing screenshot of developer tool output: see following link https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/4/8/d3f31d9c4bc7082787e6e36d23dc4145-full.jpg                                                                     As you can see in image, there are 4 successful ajax call but after another selection from dropdown it is showing some error.Need help to resolved this issue.Thanks for help

Comment: jQuery not defined. Add cdn or local path to jQuery

Comment: jQuery (a.k.a. `$`) needs to load before `bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: Thanks for help.i added jquery library before bootstarp.min.js but still having same issue. Why code is running for initial selection but not working for later selections?                                                                                
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>